# JMS queue logging/browsing for all messages (invisible consumer for queue) (OpenJMS)

Tags: logging, queue, jms, message-queue, openjms

do you have idea, if there would be some nice way to browse/log JMS queues? (I'm using OpenJMS)

For topics I can just add one consumer more and that's about it but with queues I haven't finished with a solution yet. I would like to log all the messages in certain queues and topics without "popping" them from the queue (so that the logger counld browse queues "invisible").

With **javax.jms.QueueBrowser** i can get a snapshot of the queues but that doesn't seem to provide "listener solution" - reading all the messages on the queues on infinite loop again and again and hoping that no messages happen to be both written and consumed before my snapshots - that didn't sound like a good solution.

Another option would be to create two queues for each "logical queue" - one for logger and one for the actual use - logger would then forward the messages to the "actual queue" - that could maybe work but there could be better solution?

So if somebody has a solution to get all messages in a queue by an "invisible" logger or some nice other solution for the logging, that'd be cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch to [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) (which is a much better & more popular open source JMS provider which also fully supports JMS 1.1 and J2EE 1.4) you get a number of [alternatives for monitoring and browsing queues](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-monitor-activemq.html) in particular you can just use the [Web Console](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html) or [JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html)

Comment: Even though for this particular case this wasn't possible (study assignment with JMS implementation restriction), in general ActiveMQ seems to be better choise, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for a solution and I came across an OSS project called Hermes (http://www.hermesjms.com/confluence/display/HJMS/Home). I cannot vouch for it, but I am going to be trying it out. The home page makes mention of the ability to browse / search queues.